# XML - simplexml_load_file - foreach

Tags: php, xml

I need for my project echo xml data from xml

I use simplexml_load_file

I have

```
      <group>
        <admin>
          <id>605</id>
        </admin>
        <members>
          <id>2154</id>
          <id>2256</id>
          <id>3179</id>
        </menbers>
      </group>
      <group>
        <admin>
          ....
        </admin>
        <members>
          ...
          ...
        </members>
      </group>
```

My code is

```
$soubor="platebniudaje.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($soubor);


  foreach ($xml->group as $group) { 
        echo $group->admin->id . "<br>"; 

        foreach ($group->members as $members) {
            echo $members->id . "<br>";
        }

  }
```

My output is

```
605
2154
```

but i need

```
605
2154
2256
3179
```

Can you help me? Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what your are looking for, but based only on the xml snippet in your question, this:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//group//id') as $node) {

    echo $node, PHP_EOL;
}
```

should output:

```
605
2154
2256
3179
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have one or more id's so you can loop those as well.

Note that there is a type in the xml `</menbers>`

```
foreach ($xml->group as $group) {
    echo $group->admin->id . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($group->members as $member) {
        foreach($member->id as $id)
            echo $id . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Or the shorter version if members occurs only once as pointed out by [@Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren)

```
foreach ($xml->group as $group) {
    echo $group->admin->id . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($group->members->id as $id)
        echo $id . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
605
2154
2256
3179
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/och7X)

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for your comment, I have added it to the answer.